# wagtail api : my pages dont appear in /api/cms/pages/

Tags: django, api, wagtail

I ve configured my wagtail to use the api and to serve the pages on /api/cms/pages/ endpoint. I have 9 pages created and published. But I only have the default page welcome to wagtail and its children pages being served on this endpoint :

```
{
    "meta": {
        "total_count": 3
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "meta": {
                "type": "wagtailcore.Page",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/cms/pages/2/",
                "html_url": "http://localhost/",
                "slug": "home",
                "first_published_at": "2022-06-10T09:07:28.066461Z"
            },
            "title": "Welcome to your new Wagtail site!"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "meta": {
                "type": "blog.BlogPage",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/cms/pages/10/",
                "html_url": "http://localhost/test-blog/",
                "slug": "test-blog",
                "first_published_at": "2022-06-10T09:06:33.879559Z"
            },
            "title": "test blog"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "meta": {
                "type": "blog.PostPage",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/cms/pages/11/",
                "html_url": "http://localhost/test-post/",
                "slug": "test-post",
                "first_published_at": "2022-06-10T09:06:51.974754Z"
            },
            "title": "test post"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created a few BlogPages and PostPages but they dont appear there. How can i configure my django/wagtail files so they appear?
The documentation here : https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html is not very detailed...

Here is my models.py :

```
import urllib.parse
from django.http.response import JsonResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.tags import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import Tag as TaggitTag
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
    FieldPanel,
    FieldRowPanel,
    InlinePanel,
    MultiFieldPanel,
    PageChooserPanel,
    StreamFieldPanel,
)
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.contrib.routable_page.models import RoutablePageMixin, route
from wagtail.search import index
from wagtail_headless_preview.models import HeadlessPreviewMixin
from .blocks import BodyBlock
from wagtail.api import APIField 
from .fields import TagField, CategoryField, DateTimeField
from wagtail.images.api.fields import ImageRenditionField
from django.db import models

class BasePage(HeadlessPreviewMixin, Page):

    serializer_class = None

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_component_data(self):
        if not self.serializer_class:
            raise Exception(f'serializer_class is not set {self.__class__.__name__}')

        serializer_class = import_string(self.serializer_class)

        return {
            'page_type': self.__class__.__name__,
            'page_content': serializer_class(self).data
        }

    def categories_list(self, context):
        categories = BlogCategory.objects.all()

        blog_page = context['blog_page']
        data = [{
            'name': category.name,
            'slug': category.slug,
            'url': blog_page.url + blog_page.reverse_subpage(
                "post_by_category",
                args=(
                    category.slug,
                )
            )
        } for category in categories]

        return data

    def tags_list(self, context):
        tags = Tag.objects.all()

        blog_page = context['blog_page']
        data = [{
            'name': tag.name,
            'slug': tag.slug,
            'url': blog_page.url + blog_page.reverse_subpage(
                "post_by_tag",
                args=(
                    tag.slug,
                )
            )
        } for tag in tags]

        return data

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['page_component'] = self.get_component_data()

        if 'blog_page' not in context:
            context['blog_page'] = BlogPage.objects.first()
        context['page_component']['categories_list'] = self.categories_list(context)
        context['page_component']['tags_list'] = self.tags_list(context)
        return context

    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.content_type == 'application/json':
            context = self.get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return JsonResponse(context['page_component'])
        else:
            full_path = request.get_full_path()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urllib.parse.urljoin(settings.REACT_APP_BASE, full_path))


class BlogPage(RoutablePageMixin, BasePage):
    serializer_class = "blog.serializers.BlogPageSerializer"

    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel("description", classname="full")]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function
        per_page = 2
        paginator = Paginator(self.posts, per_page)
        page = self.page_num
        try:
            posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            posts = paginator.page(1)

        context['page_component']['children_pages'] = [
            post.get_component_data()
            for post in posts
        ]
        context['page_component']['paginator'] = {
            'per_page': per_page,
            'current_page': posts.number,
            'num_pages': posts.paginator.num_pages,
        }
        context['page_component']['filter_meta'] = {                   # new
            'filter_type': getattr(self, 'filter_type', None),
            'filter_term': getattr(self, 'filter_term', None),
        }
        return context

    def get_posts(self):
        return PostPage.objects.descendant_of(self).live()

    @route(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[-\w]+)/(?:page-(?P<page_num>\d+)/)?')
    def post_by_tag(self, request, tag, page_num=1, *args, **kwargs):
        self.page_num = int(page_num)
        self.filter_type = 'tag'                                     # new
        self.filter_term = tag

        self.posts = self.get_posts().filter(tags__slug=tag)
        return self.serve(request)

    @route(r'^category/(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?:page-(?P<page_num>\d+)/)?')
    def post_by_category(self, request, category, page_num=1, *args, **kwargs):
        self.page_num = int(page_num)
        self.filter_type = 'category'                                # new
        self.filter_term = category

        self.posts = self.get_posts().filter(categories__blog_category__slug=category)
        return self.serve(request)

    @route(r'^(?:page-(?P<page_num>\d+)/)?$')
    def post_list(self, request, page_num=1, *args, **kwargs):
        self.page_num = int(page_num)
        self.posts = self.get_posts()
        return self.serve(request)


class PostPage(BasePage):
    serializer_class = "blog.serializers.PostPageSerializer"

    header_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )

    body = StreamField(BodyBlock(), blank=True)

    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through="blog.PostPageTag", blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel("header_image"),
        InlinePanel("categories", label="category"),
        FieldPanel("tags"),
        StreamFieldPanel("body"),
    ]

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('title'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]
    api_fields = ( 
    APIField(
    "header_image_url",
    serializer=ImageRenditionField("max-1000x800", source="header_image"), 
    ),
    "body",
    APIField("owner"),
    APIField("api_categories", serializer=CategoryField(source="categories")),#check if categories retrieved
    APIField("api_tags", serializer=TagField(source="tags")), 
    #APIField("pub_date",serializer=DateTimeField(format="%d %B %Y", source="first_published_at")),
    )

class PostPageBlogCategory(models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey(
        "blog.PostPage", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories"
    )
    blog_category = models.ForeignKey(
        "blog.BlogCategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_pages"
    )

    panels = [
        SnippetChooserPanel("blog_category"),
    ]

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("page", "blog_category")


@register_snippet
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=80)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("slug"),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"


class PostPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey("PostPage", related_name="post_tags")


@register_snippet
class Tag(TaggitTag):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

And here is my urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls
from blog.api import api_router
from blog.api import blog_router
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('cms-admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    path('api/blog/', include(blog_router.urls)),#/posts, categories and tags to get the api pages
    path('api/cms/', api_router.urls),#/pages to get the api pages
    path('', include('custom_comments.urls')),

    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's serving mechanism
    path('', include(wagtail_urls)),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And here is my api.py

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework import serializers
from wagtail.api.v2.router import WagtailAPIRouter
from wagtail.api.v2.views import BaseAPIViewSet, PagesAPIViewSet
from wagtail.documents.api.v2.views import DocumentsAPIViewSet
from wagtail.images.api.v2.views import ImagesAPIViewSet
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from blog.serializers import CategorySerializer, TagSerializer
from blog.models import BlogCategory, Tag
from wagtail_headless_preview.models import PagePreview
from blog.views import CategorySet, PostPageSet, TagSet
from rest_framework import routers

api_router = WagtailAPIRouter("wagtailapi")
api_router.register_endpoint('pages', PagesAPIViewSet)
api_router.register_endpoint("images", ImagesAPIViewSet)
api_router.register_endpoint("documents", DocumentsAPIViewSet)
blog_router = routers.DefaultRouter() 
blog_router.register(r"posts", PostPageSet) 
blog_router.register(r"categories", CategorySet) 
blog_router.register(r"tags", TagSet)

class PagePreviewAPIViewSet(PagesAPIViewSet):
    known_query_parameters = PagesAPIViewSet.known_query_parameters.union(
        ["content_type", "token"]
    )

    def listing_view(self, request):
        page = self.get_object()
        return page.serve(request)

    def detail_view(self, request, pk):
        page = self.get_object()
        return page.serve(request)

    def get_object(self):
        app_label, model = self.request.GET["content_type"].split(".")
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_label, model=model)

        page_preview = PagePreview.objects.get(
            content_type=content_type, token=self.request.GET["token"]
        )
        page = page_preview.as_page()
        if not page.pk:
            # fake primary key to stop API URL routing from complaining
            page.pk = 0

        return page


api_router.register_endpoint("page_preview", PagePreviewAPIViewSet)


class CategoryAPIViewSet(BaseAPIViewSet):
    base_serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    filter_backends = []
    meta_fields = []
    body_fields = ['id', 'slug', 'name']
    listing_default_fields = ['id', 'slug', 'name']
    nested_default_fields = []
    name = 'category'
    model = BlogCategory


api_router.register_endpoint("category", CategoryAPIViewSet)


class TagAPIViewSet(BaseAPIViewSet):
    base_serializer_class = TagSerializer
    filter_backends = []
    meta_fields = []
    body_fields = ['id', 'slug', 'name']
    listing_default_fields = ['id', 'slug', 'name']
    nested_default_fields = []
    name = 'tag'
    model = Tag


api_router.register_endpoint("tag", TagAPIViewSet)
```

Comment: Did you make sure to publish the new pages you created, rather than just "save draft"?

Comment: yes. plus if i go to /api/blog/posts/ endpoint, i get the json corresponding to the posts, but they should also appear under /api/cms/pages/ with type  blog.PostPage from my understanding of the doc

Comment: where can i check the content of PagesAPIViewSet?

Answer (score 0):

I created the pages as root and not as child pages of a configured site: an error message was showing in the cms menu :

```
There is no site set up for this location. Pages created here will not be accessible at any URL until a site is associated with this location. Configure a site now.
```

However i have not found how to attach several pages to a site when pages are created as root of wagtail. Only one page can be attached to a site and then only its child pages can be retrieved

Comment: How are you creating these pages? It is usually kind of hard to create a page that is NOT part of a site using the Wagtail admin UI.

If you are creating these pages programmatically, please be sure you are using the `add_child` method as noted here: https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html?highlight=add_child#wagtail.models.Page.save